# Debug while bean creation

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, javabeans

I know how to debug a normal program flow in eclipse. I want to know if there a way to debug the bean formation in eclipse using the spring framework.

Answer (score 5):

Just debug the constructor. If there is none, create a default constructor and set a breakpoint into it.

Comment: ... or just add `LOG.info("entering");` to that constructor to see the order of initialisation

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a bean aware of its initialization you can implements `InitializingBean`  interface and then implements

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      // I'm initializing
}
```

Could be a little "invasive" if it's only for debug reason, but this could be a way.

Another less invasive solution could be annotate a bean method with `@PostConstruct`.